# How would you ask 'What would you like me to call you?'

Tags: translation

I know you could use 'おなまえ は なん ですか？' to ask somebody's name, however, what polite phrase could you use/listen for when you're unsure of what to call others/others are unsure of what to call you? Is there anything close to:

'What would you like me to call you?'
'What should I call you?'
'What would you like to be called?'
etc?

Answer (score 3):

I came up with:
 
[何]{なん}て(orと)お呼びすればよろしいですか?
and
 
何て(orと)お呼びすればよろしいでしょうか?

何て(orと)呼べばいいですか? is more friendly than these.

Comment: I'm not too good with kanji. The romaji for that last one be 'Nante yobubeba ii desuka' correct? My friend tells me it's 'yobeba', not 'yobubeba'. Why is that?

Comment: Your friend is correct. It is read "yobeba". This is because the difference of conjugation term. 呼べ is a conditional term of 呼ぶ.